# SweetAlert js scrolling the page when alert panel is popped up

Tags: html, css, sweetalert

I am using sweetalert js but when alert is popped up, page scroll,
I tried to position:absolute but not working

Comment: I realized that  body.stop-scrolling class in sweetalert.css after removing it, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the css property to:

```
overlay:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Try to set `overflow: hidden;` Both X and Y

Comment: I realized that  body.stop-scrolling class in sweetalert.css after removing it, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your stylesheets:

```
html.swal2-shown,body.swal2-shown { overflow-y: hidden !important; height: auto!important;}
```